# Use number as argument for command

Tags: macros, calculations

I am unable to use a number as a parameter for a command that I have defined.

The command takes 5 numerical inputs and returns a single number.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rotateX}[5]{\pgfmathparse{cos({#5})*({#1}-{#3})-sin({#5})({#2}-{#4})+{#3}}\pgfmathresult}

\begin{document}
    \rotateX{-0.5}{3.5}{-2}{1}{40}
\end{document}
```

However, once the engine reaches the `\rotateX` command it gives the error `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)`

Do I need to do something extra in order for LaTeX to recognise that the arguments are numbers?

**Edit:**
Note that the following works on its own, the issue is with the variables that get passed to the command.

```
\pgfmathparse{cos(40)*(-0.5--2)-sin(40)(3.5-1)+-2}\pgfmathresult
```

**Edit 2:** (Using David Carlisle's suggestion)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rotateX}[5]{\pgfmathparse{cos(#5)*(#1-#3)-sin(#5)(#2-#4)+#3}\pgfmathresult}

\begin{document}
    \rotateX{-0.5}{3.5}{-2}{1}{40}
\end{document}
```

gives the following:
[image: Output of code]

Comment: you need to remove the braces, you want `-0.5` not `{-0.5}` so `#1` not `{#1}`

Comment: oh sorry, I should have updated that @DavidCarlisle. It doesn't work even when I remove the brackets `{}`

Comment: yes it will work, you must have left some in, see answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the spurious brace groups

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rotateX}[5]{\pgfmathparse{cos(#5)*(#1-#3)-sin(#5)(#2-#4)+#3}\pgfmathresult}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{cos(40)*(-0.5--2)-sin(40)(3.5-1)+-2}\pgfmathresult

\rotateX{-0.5}{3.5}{-2}{1}{40}
\end{document}
```

This is unrelated to the macro definition, `\pgfmathparse{cos({40})...` would give the same error.

Comment: I modified the answer and no, sadly that is not the solution, the expression should give -2.4579

Comment: @Tarang74 the macro gives exactly the same value as the explicit pgfmathparse call as I show.  So you may have an error with the calculation but it is unrelated to your questiuon about  macro parameters.

Comment: ohhhh nevermind, I need to use `*` between brackets. So `sin(#5)(#2-#4)` was the issue. I changed to `sin(#5)*(#2-#4)` and it worked! I must have missed the `*` last time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not related to the question

The issue was a missed `*` between brackets xD!

Working solution: (thanks David for partial help!)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rotateX}[5]{\pgfmathparse{cos(#5)*(#1-#3)-sin(#5)*(#2-#4)+#3}\pgfmathresult}
                                                              ^
\begin{document}                                              |
    \rotateX{-0.5}{3.5}{-2}{1}{40}
\end{document}
```